# Using Theory and ClassData to Parametrize Xamarin UITests

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, xamarin.uitest

I'm currently trying to make UI-Tests in Xamarin, where i want the app to be tested against different server versions.
Originally i wanted to do this like i did in unit-tests with parametrized tests by using `[Theory]` and `[ClassData]`.

Unfortunately i haven't found anything about this in the web so far regarding this nUnit construct.
Is this even possible? or is there another way to tell my xamarin UI-Test to run all my tests once for each server version?.

Many thanks in advance.

Mav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soo, the mistake i made was to assume that i could use xunit blocks for nunit tests.
My bad.
The solution is pretty simple and can be looked up here in the gitHub projects documentation:
https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestFixtureData